# Is this a wrapper script? What is the correct name for it? (Python)

Tags: python

```
execfile("es.py")
execfile("ew.py")
execfile("ef.py")
execfile("gw.py")
execfile("sh.py")

print "--Complete--"
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a kind of wrapper script, i guess, but there is no "correct name" for that as it is not very pythonic to write something like that.

One would probably write something like

```
import es
import ew
### ...

es.run() # assuming es code is in a run function
ew.run()
# ...
```

To expand on that, in python, a file is supposed to represent an unit of functionality. For example, if you implement a list type / class, you might want to put the class for this type and every function related to it into this file.

In python, a function is supposed to be an unit of execution, eg. a bunch of code that is supposed to run at once, on some particular data. It's hard to advise you without knowing the content of the files, but the content of every file executed in your snippet of code would probably benefit from being put into functions. The file division could be kept, or not depending on functionality.

Comment: Thanks! What is the advantage of doing it that way?

Answer (score 2):

It seems more like a "batch" script. It looks analogous to writing a bash or batch file in unix/windows to do a bunch of pre-defined things.  I definitely agree that it's not really a pythonic thing to do as is written though.

Comment: What would be the pythonic way?  It's the only way I could get my input raw data stuff to work.

Comment: It really depends on how the other `.py` files are written. If they're all scripts that run without using `if __name__ == '__main__'` checks, you probably do need to do it the way you've got it. Otherwise, you might simply be able to do what @ralph.amiard did.